# Newest AndEngine with API10

Tags: android, andengine

I'am starting to setup Eclipse with AndEngine and my question is.
Does newest version of AndEngine work with API10 (I choose because is the most popular)

Answer (score 0):

Andengine with GLES 2 works from API 8.

You can compile against a newer version if you want. You only need to include

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

(if you compile against API 15) in your manifest in order run your app in Android 2.2 (API 8) or later.